# Java: dependency version changes the way how warnings are treated?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

My Spring Boot application compiles with warnings:

```
$ mvn clean package
[...]
/path/to/my/file.java:[219,47] [unchecked] unchecked conversion
[WARNING]   required: List<Date>
  found:    List
[...]
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

It uses a number of Spring framework artifacts of version `3.2.13.RELEASE`.

I'm doing just single change in `pom.xml`, updating the version to `4.1.3.RELEASE`. And then *compilation of my code* fails:

```
$ mvn clean package
[...]
[ERROR] /path/to/my/file.java:[219,47] [unchecked] unchecked conversion
[ERROR] required: List<Date>
[ERROR] found:    List
[...]
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

The line which has changed from `[WARNING]` to `[ERROR]` is

```
        final List<Date> dates = dateQuery.list();
```

As I understand, the change cannot be caused by any possible change in the dependency API.

How is it possible that changing a dependency affects how warnings in my code are treated?

Comment: The API changed to accept only a `List<Date>` rather than a raw list.

Comment: @cricket_007 If API accepted a raw list, then what was the reason for the [WARNING]? I updated the post to show that no API change seems to be involved.

Comment: Not sure. I can't tell how you are using that `dates` variable